# Not authorized to report bug in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I try to report a bug in Visual Studio 2015.

I do like this:

- Press the smiley and choose "More options..."
- Choose "Report a bug"
- Log on to my Microsoft-account

After logon I get this message:

`You are not authorized to submit the feedback for this connection.`

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try navigating to https://connect.microsoft.com/directory/ and register for the "Visual Studio and .NET Framework" product.